# duplicate variable in jsp file

Tags: jsp, variables, scope, jsp-fragments

I have a jsp file in which I included twice a jspf file. In this jspf, I declared a variable :

```
boolean allEmpty = Util.isEmpty(dossierArray) 
            && Util.isEmpty(documentsUrbanArray)
            && Util.isEmpty(lienGuepardArray)
            && Util.isEmpty(lienSousEspacesGuepardArray);
```

But, I have an error : Duplicate local variable allEmpty.

How can I fix this?

Thanks all.